# Answers to "are we" or "should we" questions?

Tags: discussion, answers, unanswered-questions

It's my first Beta phase on a SE and i am not very long on the whole network.

I noticed that many Questions on the Meta Page are phrased like "are we doing this" or "should we accept this" even "do we want - that kind of question - to be on Topic".

This type of questions are mainly opinion based. So should there even be an Selected Answer? After this short Time (not even 50 views on the Questions) the usual 10 Members on the Meta Page responded to the answer and than their Opinion is set there. Mostly looking like this is now set in stone.

IMO the Answers should at least be locked for a week so everyone has the time to UP and DOWN vote and than the questioner can select one answer.

Answer (score 11):

In addition to what Godric Seer said, at this stage of site development -- and well into public beta for that matter -- it's not unusual to have "should we do X?" questions on meta.  Beta is all about shaping a site so that it will be useful and have a user base for the long haul.  And early in beta a lot of these philosophy questions get set in motion.

Also, meta is often opinion-based; while that's a sign of a weak question on *main*, meta is different.  This is where we figure out things about how to run the site; it's going to be full of opinions.

Comment: thanks for the clearification, as i said: first beta, and not long on the network at all.

Comment: This is the real answer to the question IMO. Meta is about creating some sort of cohesive community out of many disparate opinions. Main is about creating some sort of fact out of many disparate experiences.

Answer (score 9):

In Meta especially, the accepted answer is fairly meaningless.  All it really represents is a super-powered vote by the question asker to show their preference.  I don't think holding off on an accepted answer for longer than a day or two would greatly benefit the answers.

Comment: Out of interest how does rep on meta work compared with the main site? Or is that another question? ;-)

Comment: @Liath There is no rep on meta. Your rep is your rep from the main site and votes on meta do not effect rep. They are votes on the proposal and have no other baggage.

Comment: @Liath The only meta site where reputation exists in the normal sense is [meta.se] which is actually more of a hybrid between a main and a meta site...